# Error: "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-search-input'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying install `react-input-search`. I have error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-search-input'. '.../app/node_modules/react-search-input/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/react-search-input` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-search-input';`ts(7016)

Comment: I just tried using `react-search-input` in a codesandbox and it appears to be functional. Do you mind sharing a bit of your package.json file and other project details?

Comment: Please provide a sandbox where the issue is reproducible ?

Comment: Which library you want to use? `react-input-search` or `react-search-input`?

Comment: Make sure to use `react-search-input` and not `react-input-search` as in your question text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Typescript should go with Typescript NPM package, the Typescript NPM package had prefix **@types/**  on it name.
The NPM package **react-search-input** do not had Typescript package for it yet, then you can simple fix by following

1. Create file with name **globals.d.ts** and put on your source root of Typescript watcher folder
2. Put **declare module 'react-search-input'** on that file

And it should working fine

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error that you can simply solve by creating an `index.d.ts` file and then add a declaration line like this:

```js
declare module 'react-input-search';
```

You can save this file anywhere you wish but make sure to add the filepath to `tsconfig.json` like this `"typeRoots": [
      "types/index.d.ts"
    ],`

This is assuming you saved it in `types/index.d.ts`

Answer (score 1):

It's a typescript error. It means that there is no type declarations in 'react-input-search' library. There is no package 'react-input-search' with types for it, so you need to declare usage of these library in your project by creating a file with extension `.d.ts` (for example `libraries.d.ts`) and insert a line `declare module 'react-search-input';` into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create the type definition library for this library react-search-input and put it on [definitelytyped](http://definitelytyped.org) so now everyone including you can use it.
[Here is a guide](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/creating.html) with examples on how to create a type definition library.